# PHP Loop inside array

Tags: php, html

How can I loop inside an `array` in my code?

This is the static version of my script:

```
$val=array(
array("value" => "Male","label" => "Male"), 
array("value" => "Female","label" => "Femal"),  
);

my_form("Gender","select","gender",$val,"",5);
```

Then, I need to retrieve the `value` and `label` from the database.

So I customized my previous code to:

```
$div=array(
while($h = mysql_fetch_array($qwery)){
array("value" => "$h[id]","label" => "$h[div]"),    
}
);

my_form("Division","select","id_div",$div,"",5);
```

When I run it I get this `Error message`:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE), expecting ')'

Can anyone help me?

I want to loop the join data from my database into :

> input type="Select"

Comment: You can't loop inside an array

Comment: Why is this tagged `java` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a loop directly as a value in an array. Instead, loop over and add each array for each iteration of the while-loop.

Using `$div[] = "value"`, you add that value as a new element in that array.

```
$div = array(); // Initialize the array 

// Loop through results
while ($h = mysql_fetch_array($qwery)) { 
    // Add a new array for each iteration
    $div[] = array("value" => $h['id'], 
                   "label" => $h['div']);
}
```

This will create a two-dimensjonal array which would look (as an example) like

```
array(
    array(
        "value" => "Male",
        "label" => "Male"
    ), 
    array(
        "value" => "Female",
        "label" => "Female"
    )  
);
```

...which you then can look through with a `foreach` to do what you want with it.

---

If you want this to be output as options in a select-element, you could just do that directly

```
<select name="sel">
    <?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qwery)) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['div'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

ùsing a foreach can help you out. It gives you alot more overview imho.

```
$values = array(
    array("value" => "Male","label" => "Male"),
    array("value" => "Female","label" => "Femal"),
);

<select name="Select">
<?php foreach ($val as $item): ?>
    <option value="<?= $item['value']; ?>"><?= $item['label']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```